# Integral representation for system with Lyapunov-like inequality

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

Consider the system $\dot x = f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$, f continuously differentiable and
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)^TP+P\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)\preceq-I$ for all x and some $P=P^T\succ0$.

How to verify that f(x) can be written as $f(x)=\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\sigma x)xd\sigma$, and use this to show that $\forall x:f(x)^TPx+x^TPf(x)\leq-x^Tx$?

Comment: Hint for the first identity: Define $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $g(s):=f(sx)$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus (and the chain rule) between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean to rewrite the integral as:  
$\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\sigma x)xd\sigma=\int_0^1\frac{\partial g}{\partial \sigma}(\sigma)xd\sigma$
And according to the fundamental theorem of calculus between 0 and 1: 
$\int_0^1\frac{\partial g}{\partial \sigma}(\sigma)xd\sigma=g(1)x-g(0)x=\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\sigma x)xd\sigma$
which is equal to f(x).